# Wiremock JSON Response Template - Query within a Query

Tags: java, rest, api, wiremock

Let me preface this by saying that I am not a Java developer, so please excuse my ignorance and lack of ability to come up with or use a suitable solution in Java...

I am trying to create a response template which uses part of the request query, and trying to do it all in JSON due to my previously mentioned lack of Java knowledge.  Unfortunately, there is a query within a query, and the data I need is embedded within the sub-query.  See below:

`/api/v1/process?q=digsig_result%3A%22Unsigned%22+AND+netconn_count%3A%5B1+TO+99%5D&facet=True+AND+md5:D58E3582AFA99040E27B92B13C8F2280&facet=True`

I can use `{{request.query.q.[0]}}` return the entire value of `q` (`digsig_result%3A%22Unsigned%22+AND+netconn_count%3A%5B1+TO+99%5D`), but what I need to return is only the value of `md5` (`D58E3582AFA99040E27B92B13C8F2280`), which could be at any location in `q` or not exist at all.

I know grep expressions can be used in matching the URL, but it does not appear that they can be used in the response template.

It looks like it may be possible using the Opentable Wiremock Body Transformer Extension, but I didn't get very far with that before finding out that it appears that it disables the `--global-response-templating` option, which I need for responding with dynamic dates.

Apologies for needing more help than the average user here, but any potential solution I have been able to find goes beyond my very limited Java capabilities.  There may be some other third-party extension out there that does what I need, but if so I cannot find one.  If I can get this working, it would be a HUGE win for an ongoing issue, so if anyone could help me out, it would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Your URL is encoded, right? Did you test it with `POSTMAN`?